# How do i specify where persistent volume files are stored

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, lamp, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm starting to learn Kubernetes by creating LAMP stack. For my MySQL database I have created a persistent volume and persistent volume claim but now I came across a problem where I can't find the place where my PV files are stored.

This is my configuration for now:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  hostPath:
    path: "/lamp/pvstorage"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

And then at the end of my MySQL deployment file I have those lines:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pvc
```

I was hoping that my everything from Pod's `/var/lib/mysql` would be backed up at the host's `/lamp/pvstorage` directory but that doesn't seem to happen (but files are backed up somewhere else from what i can see. Database is always recreated after deleting mysql Pod).

So my question is what am I doing wrong right now and how do I specify that location?

Comment: Hi, could you please add the information about which Kubernetes solution are you using? Is it a `minikube` or `docker-desktop` or a cluster made with `kubeadm`?

Comment: I am using minikube.

Comment: The files that are created in your `PVC` with a `hostPath` are in fact stored on the `minikube` instance and not directly on your host. Depending on the `--driver` that you've used to create `minikube` you could try to run `$ minikube ssh`, `ls /lamp/pvstorage`. The files should be there. Please tell if that worked for you.

Comment: I've just tried it now and it works! You are right that those files are backed up at Minikube's docker container. Thank You very very much for helping me.

Comment: Glad that this is now resolved. Please give me some time so I can provide the answer to this question with additional explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To access the files stored on a `PVC` with a `hostPath` within a `minikube` instance that has a `--driver=docker` you will need directly login to the host (`minikube`) with for example: `$ minikube ssh` and access the files directly: `ls /SOME_PATH`

---

#### Explanation

The topic of `Persistent Volumes`, `Storage Classes` and resources that are handling whole process are quite wide and they need to be investigated on case to case basis.

The good source of baseline knowledge could be gained from official documentation and the documentation of Kubernetes solution used:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Storage: Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)*
- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/)*

Most often than not when using `minikube` (see the exception with `--driver=none`) some kind of containerization/virtualization (the layer encircling `minikube`) is used to isolate  the environment and also allow for easier creation and destruction of the instance. This is making all of the resources being stored inside of a some "box" (`Virtualbox VM`, `Docker container` etc.).

As in this example, the files that were created by `mysql` were stored on the host running `minikube` but in the `minikube` instance itself. When you create `minikube` with `--driver=docker` you create a `Docker` container that has all of the components inside of it. Furthermore by using a `PVC` with a following part of the `.spec`:

```yaml
  hostPath:
    path: "/lamp/pvstorage"
```

> #### `hostPath`
>
> A `hostPath` volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Storage: Volumes: hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)*

---

#### Example

As an example of how you can access the files:

- Follow the guide at:

  - *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Run application: Run single instance stateful application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/)*
  - Check if `mysql` is in `Running` state (`$ kubectl get pods`)
  - Run:

    - `$ minikube ssh`
    - `ls /mnt/data` (or what is specified in the `hostPath`)

```sh
docker@minikube:~$ ls /mnt/data/
auto.cnf  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  ibdata1  mysql  performance_schema
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/)*
- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Commands: SSH](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/ssh/)*

If there is a use case of having the **host** directory mounted to the `minikube` instance to specific directory you can opt for:

- `$ minikube mount SOURCE:DESTINATION`